# Socket Data Feed for other processes on local server

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to use sockets on local machine for the first time. I have a script that gets input data from an IRC server. As it takes ages for this script to connect to all the channels each time it's restarted, I want to just leave it connected all the time.

Instead of having just the one script to do all the processing of that data, I want to distribute the data to secondary processes via a socket, so that other processes running locally can all get a copy and only process the parts they want. This would mean the master process can be left running, and I can start/stop/edit the secondary processes as needed.

I admit I understand very little about this as yet. I have written 2 test scripts to try this out. One to send out test data to a socket, and one to try to read that data.

Sending script:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 12340);
socket_listen($socket);

while (!file_exists("stop.running")) {
    $message = time() . " " . rand(0, 100) . "\n"; //Just test data
    socket_write($socket, $message);
    echo "$message<br>";
    sleep(10);
}
```

Receiving script:

```
$server = array();
$server['connect'] = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 12340);
if($server['connect'] == true) {
    while(!feof($server['connect'])) {
        $server['READ_BUFFER'] = fgets($server['connect'], 2048);
        echo $server['READ_BUFFER'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    die("CANNOT CONNECT");
}
```

It will probably be very obvious to someone who knows, what I'm doing wrong or more likely, missing completely.

To clarify, I just want the secondary processes to connect and read the data. Security measures or login are not necessary. I just want the secondary process to connect and start reading. No data will be sent back to the master process.

The error I'm getting is:
PHP Warning:  socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /home/Chatbot/senddata.php on line 18

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use something like a message queue to handle the communications?

Comment: @ADyson - Hadn't heard of them before ! Looks like a possibility though. Trying to find a decent explanation atm. Any recommended links maybe ? Am I right in thinking they are stored entirely in ram, and disappear when all processes using a specific queue have finished ?

Comment: Not necessarily. There are many different implementations of queue systems, some with persistent storage, some perhaps without. Things like RabbitMQ are very popular currently. Or (for example) the big clouds all have options which might work for you and be free for small volumes (e.g. azure service bus, or something like that). You should be able to research options fairly easily and find something which suits your scenario.

Comment: @ADyson - Well - I now have a working prototype using msg_get_queue/msg_send/msg_receive using the native "System V" message queue. Thanks very much.